# iOS local notification with server data

Tags: ios, server, notifications

I'm developing an iOS app and I need to show a notification each day/week telling the user that there's some new content in the app.
Before displaying the notification I need to call a server API that tells me the number of new elements created after the last access of the user and I have to show this number on the notification.

As far as I know local notifications allow you just to schedule them and there's no way to set the message when they really are shown.

I tried to use background fetch but I read that you can never now when they are executed.

So is there a way to display something like that without push notification and making sure that the notification is shown exactly when I want?

I need it to work at least with iOS 9+

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand your question, but I'm using [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) (Firebase messaging) to send notification very simply from my server to all of the IOS who got my app (work with Android too).
Maybe it's what you need ? If yes, you'll be able to schedule notifications with your server.
PS : It's not local notification, they need internet access to receive notification.

Comment: I know that I can do what I want using push notifications but I'd like to use only local notifications.
I know that in android you can schedule a background task, so you can send a request to the server and then show the notification, but I cannot find something similar in iOS